# Shut down problem on my Lenovo Ideapad 100-14

Tags: usb, xubuntu, lenovo

I got a problem, have not installed Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new Lenovo Ideapad 100 yet, but tried it with an Usb-Stick and it freezes on the shut down screen,  what could i do to fix this problem?

Bios:

Secure boot is off
AHCI is on
Uefi is on

i bought it with DOS, so it should be possible to install Linux on it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issues with my Lenovo ideapad 100-15IBY.
 Below is link which explains how to resolve the issue:
 http://tuxicate.blogspot.bg/2015/12/ubuntu-1404-on-lenovo-ideapad-100-14iby_9.html

In short:
 In the "Exit" menu of the firmware setup, right under "Load Defaults" there is an parameter called "OS Optimized Defaults" which was set to "Other OS". The other option is "Windows 8 64-bit". This is only used when someone activates "Load Defaults" and as  expected, it enables Secure Boot, sets UEFI only boot mode and some other settings found on the setup screens.

Change the "OS Optimized Defaults" to "Win8 64bit" then load defaults and "save and exit". As expected, it activated Secure Boot but did not change any of the other values on the setup screens. This should fix the  ACPI issues. Return to the firmware setup screen, disable Secure Boot, change "OS Optimized Defaults" back to "Other OS" - but do not load defaults. After booting Ubuntu, suspend, resume, reboot and shutdown sould work well.

This solution was provided by: Tibor Bősze.